# Save list of distinct values of a variable in another variable

Tags: stata, distinct-values

I have data at the `country`-`year`-`z` level, where `z` is a categorical variable that can take(say) 10 different values (for each country-year). Each combination of `country`-`year`-`z` is unique in the dataset.

I would like to obtain a dataset at the country-year level, with a new (string) variable containing all distinct values of `z`.

For instance let's say I have the following data:

```
country     year    z
A           2000    1
A           2001    1
A           2001    2
A           2001    4
A           2002    2
A           2002    5
B           2001    7
B           2001    8
B           2002    4
B           2002    5
B           2002    9
B           2003    3
B           2003    4
B           2005    1
```

I would like to get the following data:

```
country     year    z_distinct
A           2000    1
A           2001    1 2
A           2002    2 5
B           2001    7 8
B           2002    4 5 9
B           2003    3 4
B           2003    4
```

Comment: As @Dimitriy V Masterov points out, your input and output don't tally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, perhaps more direct. If `z` is already a string variable the `string()` calls should both be omitted.

```
clear 
input str1 country year z
A 2000 1
A 2001 1
A 2001 2
A 2001 4
A 2002 2
A 2002 5
B 2001 7
B 2001 8
B 2002 4
B 2002 5
B 2002 9
B 2003 3
B 2003 4
B 2005 1
end 

bysort country year (z) : gen values = string(z[1]) 
by country year : replace values = values[_n-1] + " " + string(z) if z != z[_n-1] & _n > 1 
by country year : keep if _n == _N 
drop z 

list , sepby(country) 
     +-------------------------+
     | country   year   values |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |       A   2000        1 |
  2. |       A   2001    1 2 4 |
  3. |       A   2002      2 5 |
     |-------------------------|
  4. |       B   2001      7 8 |
  5. |       B   2002    4 5 9 |
  6. |       B   2003      3 4 |
  7. |       B   2005        1 |
     +-------------------------+
```

Comment: That is very clever.

Answer (score 3):

I think there may be some problems with your desired output given your input, but otherwise something like this should do it:

```
clear

input str1 country     year    z
"A"           2000    1
"A"           2001    1
"A"           2001    2
"A"           2001    4
"A"           2002    2
"A"           2002    5
"B"           2001    7
"B"           2001    8
"B"           2002    4
"B"           2002    5
"B"           2002    9
"B"           2003    3
"B"           2003    4
"B"           2005    1
end

gen z_distinct = "";
egen c_x_y  = group(country year)

levelsof c_x_y, local(pairs)

foreach p of local pairs {
    qui levelsof z if c_x_y == `p', clean separate(" ")
    qui replace z_distinct = "`r(levels)'" if c_x_y==`p'
}

collapse (first) z_distinct, by(country year)

sort country year
```

The code loops over country-years, calculating the observed values of z using `levelsof`, and then `collapse`s to get one row for each country-year.